# How to open phone gallery clicking a recycler view item (inside custom adapter class)

Tags: android-recyclerview, adapter, image-upload

I'm dev an app that use a recycler view to show items composed by an image and a text. The user can add an item with a custom image, doing this in a normal activity it's easy:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            launcher.launch(intent);
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK
                    && result.getData() != null) {
                Uri photoUri = result.getData().getData();
                image_to_up = photoUri;
                image_uploaded = true;
                element_image_add.setImageURI(photoUri);
            }
        }
);
```

But if I want let the user edit a recycler view item image, then the same code wont work inside the custom adapter, I get:

```
Cannot resolve method 'registerForActivityResult' in Adapter
```

So, how can I do it? How can I let the user open the gallery and select an image inside a custom adapter class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this in your Activity class:

```
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK
                && result.getData() != null) {
            Uri photoUri = result.getData().getData();
            image_to_up = photoUri;
            image_uploaded = true;
            element_image_add.setImageURI(photoUri);
        }
    }
```

);

and then create a function in the activity class that call this launcher, then call this function from the adapter class:

```
public void launch_func() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   launcher.launch(intent);
}
```

Basically you can't call the method inside the adapter so you call it from your activity class, it's not the prettiest but it should works.

Answer (score 0):

You need an activity reference to use the registerForActivityResult method inside the Adapter.
Pass the Activity variable using the constructor of the Adapter and use it like this:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = ((YourActivityClass) activity).registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK
                && result.getData() != null) {
            //your logic
        }
    });
```